# Getting values as list in list in C# from 3 joined tables tsql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, list, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008 and ASP.NET MVC.

I will try to simplify my problem with the next example:

I have tables `Parents` (`parentId, Name...`), `Children` (`childId, Name..`) and because 0 to many relationship I have one table between them, called `ParentsChildren` (`parent_Id, childId`).

Now, on my ASP.NET MVC page, I want to display all parents and their child or children.

I have tried query like this:

```sql
SELECT p.*, c.* 
FROM ParentsAS p 
LEFT JOIN Children as c ON p.parentId = c.parent_Id;
```

and tried `INNER JOIN` and so on, but still have that problem to get(in C#) that list of parents that will have inside them list of children(if they have them), else list will be empty.

Sorry in advance if there is answer for this, but it was really hard for me to type some good keywords for this kind of problem.

Any help?

Comment: are you using Entity framework, or some other ORM?

Comment: @JamesS I use ADO.NET

Comment: ok - well if just using ADO.NET then I'd probably do it as 2 separate queries (1 for parents, 1 for children joined to parentschildren) - populate 2 separate collections, and then iterate through each item in the parents collection, and populate the children from the matching items in the 2nd collection

Comment: If you were using an ORM like entity framework you could bypass this of course, as the ORM would generally map the collection property automatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```sql
SELECT      p.*, c.*
FROM        Parents            p
LEFT JOIN   ParentsChildren    pc    ON    pc.parent_Id    = p.parentId
LEFT JOIN   Children           c     ON    c.childId       = pc.childId
```

### [See working sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d257b/5)

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I needed! Any idea how could I, this result of the query, put into the list, for example <List> allParents, but without having duplicated values, like for Jon Doe, so there will be only one object in the list for him, but inside the <List> allParents there will be <List> theirChildren, and it will have 2 objects with Jerry and Jannette

Comment: @DixD13 - Do you already have classes created for Parents and Children?